# Is there any Google API library for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-api, npm

Is there a Node.js library that covers all of Google's APIs into a single API? (Google Contacts, Google Calendar, Google Geolocations API, etc.)

Answer (score 22):

**Note**: I'm the author of `googleapis` module.

Google released an officially supported node client library for its APIs. https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client It's also available on npm:

```
npm install googleapis
```

Load an API with its handle and version, then make requests:

```
googleapis.discover('urlshortener', 'v1').execute(function(err, client) {
  // make requests here
  client.urlshortener.url.get({ shortUrl: 'http://goo.gl/DdUKX' }).execute(console.log);
});
```

It also supports batch requests and OAuth 2.0.

Comment: FYI, there aren't any Google+ APIs to access the albums yet...you have to go through the Picasa albums API

Comment: Does this include the [Google Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/)?

Comment: "This client library is supported but in maintenance mode only." - is there some other module that is actively maintained and should be used instead?

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried this but found it via npmjs.org search: https://npmjs.org/

https://github.com/JimmyBoh/node-google-api

Comment: This uses Google's discovery API and is therefore probably correct - and (per package documentation) automagically up to date.

Answer (score 1):

The Temboo SDK is available for Node.js, and provides a uniform way of accessing a fair swath of the Google APIs:

- OAuth authentication
- Analytics
- Checkout
- Calendar
- Contacts
- Directions
- DistanceMatrix
- Drive
- Elevation
- GeoCoding
- Gmail
- Places
- Plus
- Spreadsheets

See https://live.temboo.com/library/Library/Google/ -- the SDK is an open download, but you need a (free) Temboo account to do anything with it.

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo.)